# IBM Cloud Activity Tracker: How to route logdna to logdna across accounts?

Tags: ibm-cloud, terraform-provider-ibm, logdna

I have used Terraform in an IBM Cloud multi-account setup to define [Activity Tracker Event Routing](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/activity-tracker?topic=activity-tracker-about) [targets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/atracker_target) and [routes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/IBM-Cloud/ibm/latest/docs/resources/atracker_route) and had hoped that I can stream logdna to logdna across account boundaries.

```
resource "ibm_atracker_target" "atracker_logdna_target" {
  target_type = "logdna"
  logdna_endpoint {
    target_crn = data.ibm_resource_instance.testacc_atracker_resource_instance.id
    ingestion_key = "some-ingestion-key"
  }
  name = "my-logdna-target"
  region = "eu-de"
}
```

```
resource "ibm_atracker_route" "atracker_route" {
  name = "my-a2a-route"
  rules {
    target_ids = [ ibm_atracker_target.atracker_logdna_target.id ]
    locations = [ "global", "us-south", "eu-de" ]
  }
```

}

I don't seem to have incoming events. How can I check that events are routed successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Terraform code in my question works, but I had to change something in my test setup:

- [enable VRF and service endpoints](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-vrf-service-endpoint)
- [change the service plan to at least 7 days data retainment](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/log-analysis?topic=log-analysis-upgrade), it did not working with just the streaming logs (Lite plan)